# jinja for loop inside jinja for loop

Tags: html, loops, for-loop, jinja2

I want a jinja loop inside of a jinja loop unfortunately I keep getting errors cause theres so many brackets. how can I have a for loop in a for loop like this?

```
{% for stock in stocks%}
  <tr>
      <td>{{stock.id}}</td>
      <td>{{stock.price}}</td>
      {% for i in stock_list %}
      <th>{{stock.{{i}}}}th>
      {% endfor %}
  </tr>
```

Error Message was: expected name or number

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the nested brackets '{{stock.{{i}}}}'.
Just use the i variable directly: {{stock.i}} or {{stock[i]}}.
Your describe is not explicit, I can't test it. You can try it.